# Calculating Prices with List Box

Tags: vb.net, listbox

Calculating PreTax, Tax, and Total amounts based on items in list box. Here's how it looks currently when executed:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3W0gSES_-fNMmdnU1VTSzR2dFk

Here is the code I have so far:

```
'load ListBox with test data:
    For dblPrices As Double = 1 To 4
        lstPrices.Items.Add(dblPrices.ToString("c2"))
    Next dblPrices

    'calculate pretax total:

    Dim dblPretaxTotal As Double = 0
    Dim dblSelectedPrice As Double

    For intTax As Integer = 0 To lstPrices.Items.Count - 1
        lstPrices.SelectedIndex = 0
        Dim strPrice As String
        strPrice = Convert.ToString(lstPrices.SelectedItem)
        Double.TryParse(strPrice, dblSelectedPrice)
        dblPretaxTotal = dblSelectedPrice
    Next intTax
```

I only have it programmed to calc and display the PreTax Total currently. It should show $10.00. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You did not ask a question, but if you are trying to sum, you need something to accumulate `dblTotal += dblSelectedPrice`  there is no read for that loop, it is just changing `dblPretaxTotal` to a new value each time.  Use the debugger for this sort of problem.  Thats what it is for

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out!

Comment: I want to answer this one can you pls make it more detailed? What do you want to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is the failed double conversion.

try this:

```
dblPretaxTotal += Double.Parse(strPrice, NumberStyles.Currency) * taxRate;
```

instead of Double.TryParse() without checking for the result. NumberStyles.Currency and a taxrate was also missing.